# Is it possible to create a VM from an existing OS?

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-workstation

I have an existing OS (Ubuntu server) on a separate HDD that I'd like to clone to a VM (preferable VMware or similar capable or running from windows). Is that possible?

Comment: I guess your question is: How can I convert a disk image to a VMware disk image?

Comment: The answer is, yes it is possible. In fact there are multiple ways to do it. Finding the best approach for your scenario requires a bit more knowledge about your requirements.

Comment: @kasperd As Dylan Knoll mentions below, for the general case, VMWare Converter is the right tool for the job. If there are reasons to not use the best tool for the job, they should be mentioned up-front.

Comment: What in the world is the down vote for?

Comment: Mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".  Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.

Comment: "[Virt-p2v](http://libguestfs.org/virt-p2v.1.html) converts a physical machine to run virtualized on KVM, managed by libvirt, OpenStack, oVirt, Red Hat Enterprise Virtualisation (RHEV), or one of the other targets supported by [virt-v2v(1)](http://libguestfs.org/virt-v2v.1.html)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VMware vCenter Converter](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/info/slug/infrastructure_operations_management/vmware_vcenter_converter_standalone/5_5#product_downloads) sounds like the best tool for the job.